# How to set a cart fragment when action bar item is clicked (on option item selected) in the same activity when i am in any other fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This is Main Activity Where I have created Fragments through mobile_navigation.xml
Now in Action Bar i have set 2 items one is search which is another activity which i have sent through intent.Now for cart item i want to send it to Cart fragment of the same Activity.How do i send it??
I am new to Development Please Help

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

```
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    setContentView(binding.getRoot());

    setSupportActionBar(binding.appBarMain.toolbar);
    DrawerLayout drawer = binding.drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView = binding.navView;
    // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
    // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
    mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
            R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_my_archaka,R.id.nav_my_cart)
            .setOpenableLayout(drawer)
            .build();
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);


    parentframelayout = findViewById(R.id.parentframelayout);






}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
            || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.main_search) {

        Intent searchintent = new Intent(this, SearchActivity.class);
        startActivity(searchintent);
        return true;
    }

    if (id == R.id.main_cart) {
```

////how to send to cart fragment of this same activity;

```
        return true;

    } 

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Create an action in your navgraph and add this code on if() condition:

`Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_fragment1_to_fragment2);`